# Heading with chapter but without number and without word "chapter

Tags: header-footer, chapters, fancyhdr

I'm writing my thesis and I'struggling with the header

In the header I want to have just the chapter name with no number and no "Chapter 1."

Here is what I'm using now

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\huge}      % To supress the word "Chapter"

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[C]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
```

Would also be nice to have the page number right and left depending on odd or even number.

Have anyone a clue?

Thank a lot.

Gio

**Update**

The solutions of Bernard and Pieter worked for me. I forgot to place `twoside` in the `\documentclass` option. Without `twoside` page number will be on the right side on each page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have to load `titlesec`, you can use the `[pagestyles]` option to use its companion package `titleps`, which  makes it much simpler (no marks required):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
{\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\centering\huge} % To suppress the word "Chapter"
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newpagestyle{mine}{%
\headrule
\sethead{}{\chaptertitle}{}
\setfoot{}{\thepage}{}
}
\pagestyle{mine}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A First Chapter}

\lipsum[1-12]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help, your solution worked!

Answer (score 0):

You would have to redefine `\chaptermark` to only include the chapter name.

Like

```
\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
```

Regarding the page number, use

```
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}
```

or

```
\fancyfoot[RE,LO]{\thepage}
```

depending on which side. If you also want to have the page numbers the same on the first page of a chapter:

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \fancyhead{}
  \renewcommand\headrule{}}
```

Comment: Work for me Thank you a lot!